# NOT REGEXP_MATCH not working in Google Data Studio

Tags: mysql, regex, looker-studio, re2

I have a MySQL Data Set connected as a Data Source in Google Data Studio, and I'm creating custom fields to use in reports.
From the respective Google support pages, I have seen that the `NOT REGEXP_MATCH` formula should work ( [See here on last line](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7064476?hl=en) ) but it doesn't seem to.

This code works:

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(receipt,"75") AND REGEXP_MATCH(gameid,"75") THEN "0.75"
END
```

This code doesn't work ("*Creating field failed: try again later*"). In addition, from the editor, I can see that when using `NOT`, the `THEN` color turns back to black, which indicates that the editor doesn't understand it correctly (as it should turn purple):

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(receipt,"75") AND NOT REGEXP_MATCH(gameid,"75") THEN "0.75"
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recreated the formula using a Google Sheets Data Source and it works as expected. One thing to try is whether explicitly stating the [ELSE clause](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724#else-results) resolves the issue:

**Number Field**

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(receipt, "75") AND NOT REGEXP_MATCH(gameid, "75") THEN 0.75
  ELSE 0
END
```

**Text Field**

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(receipt, "75") AND NOT REGEXP_MATCH(gameid, "75") THEN "0.75"
  ELSE "Other Value"
END
```

[Link to Google Data Studio Report with the Data Source and Embedded Google Sheet](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/8328237)